# Does disabling norms on one field give advantage over other fields when searching multiple fields?

Tags: java, lucene, scoring

I have a number of fields that either only ever contain one term or I don't want them to be disavantaged if they do have a greater number of terms, and I never boost the field so I disable norms for these fields with Field.Index.ANALYZED_NO_NORM or Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED_NO_NORM.

But now if I'm searching using two fields

i.e

```
fielda:term1 OR fieldb:term2
```

and fielda has norms enabled and fieldb doesn't, doesn't that mean that documents that match fieldb are more likely to score better than documents that match fielda because the score for a document matching just fielda will end up with a lower score in the

```
weight = tf * idf * fieldnorm calculation.
```

because fieldnorm will be less than one if that field contains more than one term

Thats not what I wanted,  I just wanted a document matching on fieldb which contained three terms to score as well as a match on a document fieldb with one term

Have I understood this right, all the discussion about fieldnorm focus on the fact that it takes up memory and it is not neccessary if your field only contains one term I've read no discussion of how it effects the results because of the apparent advantage a field with norms disabled has over a field with norms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My recommandation would be not to mix queries on fields whose norms are disabled with queries on standard fields. The point of disabling norms is to save space when a query is only used as a filter (and not contributing to the score).

The elegant way of doing what you want would be to have two different similarities for your fields. However, this feature ([per-field similarity](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-2236)) is only available in the development version currently.

Comment: Hi, yes Im aware that the similarity model has been opened up alot in Lucene 4.0 but unfortunately I cannot use that. Im not so sure norms are ONLY disabled for filters in my case Im disabling them to protect against a one-many scenario when multiple values get added to one field and cannot be fairly compared against the same field when it only has one value. But you havent answered whether my assertion is correct that a fied without norms has an implicit boost compared to a field with norms.

Comment: This is correct. Looking at the definition of computeNorm in DefaultSimilarity http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/branches/branch_3x/lucene/core/src/java/org/apache/lucene/search/DefaultSimilarity.java the normalization factor will be 1 for fields with norms disabled and 1/sqrt(numTerms) for standard fields. You could override computeNorm to multiply its result by sqrt(3) so that fields with 3 terms will have the same norm as fields with norms disabled (but this is kind of a hack). Note that if you modify the definition of computeNorm, you will need to reindex to make changes visible.

Comment: Okay yes no disabling norms acts as if the field just contained a single term so actually any field that only contained single values would also be advantaged in comparison to other fields, although this may be balanced out by the fact that the idf is likely to work the opposite way because if field only contains a single values may be more common over the index. Now even if I had per field similarity I'm not quite sure what approach I would take